# 403 Bad Request sending a post request from URI with name parameter

Tags: spring, spring-security

I have my post request filtered after JWT Authentication (and even if I disable it as following code). Not sure if I do anything wrong.
URI REQUEST: localhost:8016/api/v1/VILLA+ITALIA/table
PARAMETER: name

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x8pgV.png)

````
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.httpBasic().disable().formLogin().disable()
              .csrf().ignoringAntMatchers(API_URL_PREFIX, H2_URL_PREFIX)
              .and()
              .headers().frameOptions().sameOrigin() // for H2 Console
              .and()
              .cors()
              .and()
              .authorizeRequests()
              .antMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, RESTAURANT_URL).permitAll()
              .antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, RESTAURANT_URL).permitAll()
              .antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, TOKEN_URL).permitAll()
              .antMatchers(HttpMethod.DELETE, TOKEN_URL).permitAll()
              .antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, SIGNUP_URL).permitAll()
              .antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, REFRESH_URL).permitAll()
              .antMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, SERVICES_URL).permitAll()
              .antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, SERVICES_URL).permitAll()
              .antMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, BOOKINGS_URL).permitAll()
              .antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, BOOKINGS_URL).permitAll()
              .antMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, CUSTOMERS_URL).permitAll()
              .antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, CUSTOMERS_URL).permitAll()
              .antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, TABLES_URL).permitAll()
//              .mvcMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, "/api/v1/restaurants**")
//              .hasAuthority(RoleEnum.ADMIN.getAuthority())
              .anyRequest().authenticated()
              .and()
              //.addFilterBefore(new JwtAuthenticationFilter(new JwtManager(), (UserService) userService), UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class)
//              .oauth2ResourceServer(oauth2ResourceServer -> oauth2ResourceServer.jwt(
//                    jwt -> jwt.jwtAuthenticationConverter(getJwtAuthenticationConverter())))
              .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS);
    } ```
````

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

There are nothing antMatchers sentence which match with "/api/v1/VILLA+ITALIA/table" url.

Try it using the following sentence:

```
 .antMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, "/api/v1/**/table").permitAll()
```

Comment: I have modified the uri /api/v1/restaurants/{restName}/table and .antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, ""/api/v1/restaurants").permitAll() but it won't work

Comment: Did you use the wildcard character? /api/v1/*/restaurant p.e.